# SQL - Multiple Joins (News Feeds)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to create a News Feed for my website, that shows 3 types of information: Questions, Answers (related to questions) and Discussions.

I have a main table called Events which records all activities of the platform, and a separate table for each type of record (Users, Questions, Answers and Discussions) as shown below:

Table Events

```
EventID  EventType   fkQuestionID   fkAnswerID   fkDiscussionID
1        Question    1              NULL         NULL
2        Question    2              NULL         NULL
3        Discussion  NULL           NULL         1
4        Answer      1              1            NULL
5        Question    3              NULL         NULL
6        Discussion  NULL           NULL         2
7        Answer      2              2            NULL
8        Discussion  NULL           NULL         3
```

Table Questions

```
QuestionID  fkUserID    QuestionTitle
1           1           Who is Homer Simpson?
2           2           What is the capital of Madagascar?
3           3           What superpower would you choose?
```

Table Answers

```
AnswerID    fkQuestionID    fkUserID    Answer
1           1               2           He is a characted of a...
2           2               4           The capital is...
```

Table Discussions

```
DiscussionID    fkUserID    DiscussionTitle
1               3           The best day of my life
2               1           The worst zombie movies
3               2           The funiest scens of...
```

Table Users

```
UserID  Name
1       Jack
2       Ana
3       Rose
4       Brad
```

This is the expected result:

[image]

So far, I created the following query:

```
SELECT E.EventID,
E.EventType,
E.fkQuestionID,
E.fkAnswerID,
E.fkDiscussionID,
Q.QuestionTitle,
U1.Name as QuestionBy,
A.Answer,
U2.Name as AnswerBy,
D.DiscussionTitle,
U3.Name as PostBy
FROM events E
LEFT JOIN questions Q ON Q.QuestionID=E.fkQuestionID
LEFT JOIN users U1 ON U1.UserID=Q.fkUserID
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT fkQuestionID, MAX(AnswerID) AS AnswerID
FROM answers
GROUP BY fkQuestionID
) t ON t.fkQuestionID = E.fkQuestionID  //show the last answer
LEFT JOIN answers A ON A.pkAnswerID = t.AnswerID
LEFT JOIN users U2 ON U2.UserID=A.fkUserID
LEFT JOIN dicussions D ON D.DiscussionID=E.fkDiscussionID
LEFT JOIN users U3 ON U3.UserID=D.fkUserID
```

Given that the table Events will store a large amount of rows, I am in doubt about few things, also regarding the slow performance:

- The current query is already taking +2s to process (30 rows). As I am making a type of News Feed page, instead of making a huge query with all data at once, I am considering to use a loop and make several separate queries to bring the remaining information for each type of Event and load it with ajax (decrease server response and increase the impression of page load). Is it a stupid idea?
- For the join with the table Users, is there a better way instead of using many LEFT JOINS (U1, U2, U3) for each type of Event? I am afraid of using many LEFT JOINS for all types of events.
- If someone writes a new Answer, I tried to bring only the last Answer (max AnswerID) related to the Question. However, I am struggling to hide the other events related to the same Question (in order to avoid duplicated feeds/events of the same question). Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: Please post plain text instead of images, so we can copy and paste into sqlfiddle.

Comment: You can't write a conditional join. What you normally do is write multiple queries that each join with a different table, and combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: @Barmar : edited as plain text, tks!

Comment: Got it, no problem I'll try to figure out with your tips, tks anyway. What I did is a very inefficient way, although it works for now... I made a query first just to bring the events array, then I made a loop (using php) with different queries to bring the remaining data (user, title, answer, etc) for each type of event.

Comment: Or just use a series of left joins instead of union.

Comment: @Shadow tks for your tip, I am working now with LEFT JOINS, however I am trying to figure out how to deal with the last 2 bullet points of my question (bring 2 users and avoid duplication of same event). Also, using a lot of left joins could affect too much in the performance?

Comment: Pls see Barmar's 3rd comment on showing what you have tried. Not to mention the fact that only the 1st bullet point is formulated as a question, so I assumed that is the one causing you the problem, not the rest.

Comment: Looping through records is bad, never do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally see no reason for the Events table at all.

I would solve this by A UNION ALL query and I would link the question and answer on the same line of the query. Something like:

```
SELECT 
'Question' as EventType,
Q.QuestionID,
t.AnswerID,
NULL as DiscussionID,
Q.QuestionTitle,
U1.Name as QuestionBy,
A.Answer,
U2.Name as AnswerBy,
NULL as DiscussionTitle,
NULL as PostBy
FROM  questions Q 
JOIN users U1 ON U1.UserID=Q.fkUserID
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT fkQuestionID, MAX(AnswerID) AS AnswerID
FROM answers
GROUP BY fkQuestionID
) t ON t.fkQuestionID = Q.QuestionID  
LEFT JOIN answers A ON A.pkAnswerID = t.AnswerID
LEFT JOIN users U2 ON U2.UserID=A.fkUserID


UNION ALL

SELECT 
'Discussion' as EventType,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
D.DiscussionTitle,
U3.Name as PostBy
FROM  dicussions D 
LEFT JOIN users U3 ON U3.UserID=D.fkUserID
```

Of course you may want to have where clauses to limit to a particular user. If you want the questions they have answered as well as the ones they asked, then add another UNION ALL for that when you look by user.

At this point you should also check your indexes to make sure you have them on all the join fields.

Comment: Nice, it worked much faster with the UNION ALL (0.7s). However even with the LEFT JOIN with the table Answers, the query only brings questions that were answered already. How can I adjust to also bring unanswered questions as well?

Comment: and differ the EventType as Questions (unanswered) and Answers

Comment: I solved with another UNION together with the table Questions and retrieve the unanswered Questions